# Rdlc page breaks in dynamic subreports

Tags: c#, rdlc

I have a rdlc report with some static information at the begining, and after this information there is a subreport that will render N child subreports depending on the datasource, I need the data of each subreport to be rendered in a separate page. The structure is like this pseudo code:

```
<Report>
    <Tablix>....</Tablix>
    <SubReport>
         subreports.rdlc
    </SubReport>
</Report>
subreport.rdlc
<Report>
      <Tablix>
         <TablixRow>some information</TablixRow>
         <TablixRow details>
             <SubReport>othersubreport.rdlc</SubReport>
             <PageBreak>
                  <BreakLocation>End</BreakLocation>
             </PageBreak>
         </TablixRow>
      </Tablix>

 </Report>
```

I placed a page break at the end of each subreport in the details row group of the table, but it seems to be a problem with page break inside subreports. Is this a known issue? Is there any workaround to solve this?

Answer (score 1):

Try replacing the first subreport with a `List` component. And make sure that `KeepTogether` is set to false. If this didn't do the trick try replacing the second report as well by using rectangles.

Take a look at [this tutorial](http://gotreportviewer.com/masterdetail/index.html) where both methods are explained.